# Zip seems not to wait for Observable to emit data

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm trying to run 2 parallel requests using volley in order to update a database (using DBFlow). One table on the DB can be populated only once both requests has been made and their data saved (FKs).

Given the example bellow, I want both sectors/employees fetch/insert to run in parallel and then, once the inserts are done, to save the contracts.

```
/**
 * Update the sectors, employees and their contracts
 * @return An Observable to watch for the process to complete
 *
 *  sectorsFetch______sectorsInsert________contractsInsert
 *  employeesFetch____employeesInsert___/
 */
public static Observable<Void> updateEverything() {
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting update...");
        Observable<JSONArray> employeesFetch = Observable.from(ForumAPI.getInstance().getEmployees());
        Observable<List<Contract>> employeesInsert = employeesFetch.flatMap(new Func1<JSONArray, Observable<List<Contract>>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<List<Contract>> call(JSONArray employees) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Employee list fetched");
                return saveEmployees(employees);
            }
        });

        Observable<JSONArray> sectorsFetch = Observable.from(ForumAPI.getInstance().getSectors());
        Observable<Void> sectorsInsert = sectorsFetch.flatMap(new Func1<JSONArray, Observable<Void>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Void> call(JSONArray sectors) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Sector list fetched");
                return saveSectors(sectors);
            }
        });

        return Observable.zip(sectorsInsert, employeesInsert, new Func2<Void, List<Contract>, Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call(Void aVoid, List<Contract> contracts) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Sectors and employees saved. Saving contracts");
                return saveContracts(contracts);
            }
        });

    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        return Observable.error(e);
    }
}
```

Note : ForumAPI getEmployees/Sectors returns Future both.

Bellow is the save methods.

```
/**
 * Parse and save an array of sectors
 * @param jsonSectors The array of sector to save
 * @return An Observable to watch for the process to complete.
 */
private static Observable<Void> saveSectors(JSONArray jsonSectors) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Transforming JSON sectors to object");
    List<Sector> sectList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonSectors.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonSect = jsonSectors.getJSONObject(i);
            Sector sect = Sector.build(jsonSect);
            sectList.add(sect);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, sectList.size() + " sectors fetched. Saving...");
        ForumDB.getDB().executeTransaction(
                FastStoreModelTransaction.insertBuilder(
                        FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Sector.class)
                ).addAll(sectList).build());

        Log.d(TAG, "Sector list saved");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to parse sector list. " + e.getMessage());
        return Observable.error(e);
    }
    return Observable.empty();
}
/**
 * Parse and save an array of sectors
 * @param jsonSectors The array of sector to save
 * @return An Observable to watch for the process to complete.
 */
private static Observable<Void> saveSectors(JSONArray jsonSectors) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Transforming JSON sectors to object");
    List<Sector> sectList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonSectors.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonSect = jsonSectors.getJSONObject(i);
            Sector sect = Sector.build(jsonSect);
            sectList.add(sect);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, sectList.size() + " sectors fetched. Saving...");
        ForumDB.getDB().executeTransaction(
                FastStoreModelTransaction.insertBuilder(
                        FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Sector.class)
                ).addAll(sectList).build());

        Log.d(TAG, "Sector list saved");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to parse sector list. " + e.getMessage());
        return Observable.error(e);
    }
    return Observable.empty();
}

/**
 * Parse and save an array of employees
 * @param jsonEmployees The array of employee to save
 * @return An Observable to watch for the process to complete.
 */
private static Observable<List<Contract>> saveEmployees(JSONArray jsonEmployees) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Transforming JSON employees to object");
    List<Person> empList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Contract> contractList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonEmployees.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonEmp = jsonEmployees.getJSONObject(i);
            Person emp = Person.build(jsonEmp);
            empList.add(emp);
            JSONArray jsonContracts = jsonEmp.getJSONArray("sectors");
            for (int j = 0; j <  jsonContracts.length(); j++) {
                Contract contract = new Contract();
                contract.setSectorId(jsonContracts.getJSONObject(j).getInt("id"));
                contract.setPersonForumId(emp.getForumId());
                contractList.add(contract);
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, empList.size() + " employees fetched. Saving...");
        ForumDB.getDB().executeTransaction(
                FastStoreModelTransaction.insertBuilder(
                        FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Person.class)
                ).addAll(empList).build());
        Log.d(TAG, "Employee list saved");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to parse employee list. " + e.getMessage());
        return Observable.error(e);
    }
    return Observable.just(contractList);
}

/**
 * Save a list of contract
 * @param contracts The list of contract to save
 * @return An Observable to watch for the process to complete.
 */
private static Void saveContracts(List contracts) {
    ForumDB.getDB().executeTransaction(
            FastStoreModelTransaction.insertBuilder(
                    FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Contract.class)
            ).addAll(contracts).build());
    Log.d(TAG, "Contract list saved");

    return null;
}
```

The problem is, when subscribing on that global observable from an Android activity, my observer onCompleted get called right after sectorFetch emit data (neither sectorInsert nor my zip are called).

Bellow is the log

```
D/com.xx.observable.DataUpdater: Starting update...
D/com.xx.helper.ForumAPI: Requesting employee list
D/com.xx.helper.ForumAPI: Request added to queue...
D/com.xx.helper.ForumAPI: Requesting sector list
D/com.xx.helper.ForumAPI: Request added to queue
D/com.xx.observable.DataUpdater: Sector list fetched
D/com.xx.observable.DataUpdater: Transforming JSON sectors to object
D/com.xx.observable.DataUpdater: 8 sectors fetched. Saving...
D/com.xx.observable.DataUpdater: Sector list saved
D/com.xx.activity.Startup: onCompleted reached
```

I can't find what is wrong. Is one of my observable is emitting something so my zip get called before it should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `zip` documentation in 1.1.6 has been updated to describe this case:

> The operator subscribes to its sources in order they are specified and completes eagerly if  one of the sources is shorter than the rest while unsubscribing the other sources. Therefore, it  is possible those other sources will never be able to run to completion (and thus not calling  `doOnCompleted()`. This can also happen if the sources are exactly the same length; if source A completes and B has been consumed and is about to complete, the operator detects A won't be sending further values and it will unsubscribe B immediately. For example: `zip(Arrays.asList(range(1, 5).doOnCompleted(action1), range(6, 5).doOnCompleted(action2)), (a) -> a)` `action1` will be called but `action2` won't.

In other words, don't zip with `empty()`. You can zip with `Observable.<Void>just(null)` and ignore that rail.

Comment: jeee.... Was struggling with this for hours. Thank you. I'll be more focused on the javadoc than the reactiveX doc next time.

Comment: The ReactiveX site is out of my direct control and otherwise somewhat slower to get updates.

Comment: That doc still feels a bit misleading. I was under the impression that if source A completes, then B will be unsubscribed from immediately and no more emissions will come out of B. Yet it seems that `zip` will wait for as many more emissions from B as A produced prior to A's completion, in order for the new observable produced by `zip` to complete.

Comment: `zip` will try to create as many rows of data as it can. If it determines it is no longer possible to create any further rows, it will stop the flows.

Comment: Yep, makes sense. Thanks for the clarification